# How to solve system UI lagging / max fan speed by leveraging dedicated Quadro graphics on Dell Precision 7510?

Tags: 20.04, graphics, performance, fan

My laptop ( DELL Precision 7510 ) comes with a heavy-weight configuration ( Intel i7-6280hq, 32GB DDR4 ram, Quadro M200M 4GB ram, SSD 1TB with 2gbps I/O throughput ), running Ubuntu 20.04

In spite of this, during the first few minutes after boot and very often afterwards, cooling fans are running at full speed and the system UI (Gnome), mouse pointer and apps (e.g. Firefox) are very laggy.

All I am running is Firefox with 30-40 tabs and a memory footprint of about 2-3GB (based on `about:performance`)

Ubuntu's `system monitor`shows all 8 cpus nearly at 100% and a 12GB (our of 31GB) RAM usage.

I thought it could depend on the system using only intel integrated graphics, but for example `prime-select query` shows **nvdia**.

`sensors` show

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +74.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +74.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +72.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +74.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

**How can I resolve the cpu bottleneck so the system runs smooth while leveraging the generous amount of ram installed to run many apps and browser tabs?**

Comment: Try using Google Chrome and check if you experience the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the cause was a background app using exessive resources, though with Firefox it got much worse.

It didn't show up in `system monitor` but `htop` seems to give a great overview of what really uses so much resources